# Jquery not updating css onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a JQuery problem today here's the code dump to start us off

```
$(function() {
    var distance = 0;
    $('.right').click(function() {
        distance -= 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%)')
        console.log(distance);
    });
    $('.left').click(function() {
        distance += 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%);')
        console.log(distance);
    });
});
```

What this code is doing is move width of the users page 100% to the left or 100% to the right. When I click a button with a class name of 'right' it works all fine, but when I click a class name of 'left' it displays it in the console as it should but it doesn't move the page, it needs me to press another button before it updates.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `;` from this line:

```
$('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%);')
//                                                             ^ Remove it
```

---

```
$('.left').click(function() {
    distance += 100;
    $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distance + '%)')
    console.log(distance);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think all I needed was another set of eyes on it :)